# Error with to string method my code is below

Tags: queue, tostring

Trying to code this and its driving me crazy i know its something simple 
my question is on the toString method i am getting compile error Cannot find symbol varible getNext also if you can check the rest of the methods for accuracy that would be greatly appreciated

```
    public class Turner_A06Q2
   {
   /**
  * Program entry point for queue testing.
  * @param args Argument list.
  */    
   public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     LinkedQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedQueue<Integer>();

    System.out.println("QUEUE TESTING");

    queue.enqueue(3);
    queue.enqueue(7);
    queue.enqueue(4);
    System.out.println(queue.first());
    queue.dequeue();        
    queue.enqueue(9);
    queue.enqueue(8);
    System.out.println(queue.first());        
    System.out.println(queue.dequeue());
    System.out.println(queue.first());        

    System.out.println("The size of the queue is: " + queue.size());
 System.out.println("The queue contains:\n" +queue.toString());        
  }

/**
 * LinkedQueue represents a linked implementation of a queue.
 * 
 * @author Java Foundations
 * @version 4.0
 */
   public static class LinkedQueue<T> implements QueueADT<T>
{
    private int count;
    private LinearNode<T> head, tail; //front, back

    /**
     * Creates an empty queue.
     */
    public LinkedQueue()
    {
        count = 0;
        head = tail = null;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified element to the tail of this queue.
     * @param element the element to be added to the tail of the queue
     */
    public void enqueue(T element)
    {
        LinearNode<T> node = new LinearNode<T>(element);

        if (isEmpty())
            head = node;
        else
            tail.setNext(node);

        tail = node;
        count++;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the element at the head of this queue and returns a
     * reference to it. 
     * @return the element at the head of this queue
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the queue is empty
     */
    public T dequeue() throws EmptyCollectionException
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("queue");

        T result = head.getElement();
        head = head.getNext();
        count--;

        if (isEmpty())
            tail = null;

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a reference to the element at the head of this queue.
     * The element is not removed from the queue.  
     * @return a reference to the first element in this queue
     * @throws EmptyCollectionsException if the queue is empty
     */
    public T first() throws EmptyCollectionException
    {
        return head.getElement();
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this queue is empty and false otherwise. 
     * @return true if this queue is empty 
     */
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return count==0;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements currently in this queue.
     * @return the number of elements in the queue
     */
    public int size()
    {
        return count;
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of this queue. The front element
     * occurs first, and each element is separated by a space. If the
     * queue is empty, returns "empty".
     * @return the string representation of the queue
     */
    public String toString()
    {
         if (isEmpty()) {
            return " ";
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        LinearNode<T> next = head.getNext;
        while(next != null){
            sb.append(" ").append(next.getElement());
            next = next.getNext();
        }
            return sb.toString();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without sharing with us the code for `LinearNode`, I don't think we can help you. Can you post a minimal complete example? That would be enough code that, if we wanted to compile and run the code ourselves, we'd be able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

it is a queue and you are trying to print the contents of a queue without actually iterating over it hence, the error.

Try something like this:

```
for (E element : queue)
{
 System.out.println(queue.get(i).toString());
}
```